# Php array external link open in a new window

Tags: php, wordpress

I have added a button to my wordpress admin panel that clicks through to a external link. Im using google as an example. However i would like to make it that when the link is clicked it opens in a new tab/window. How would i achieve this with php?

```
function my_create_widget_admin_menu(){
add_menu_page( 'Widget', 'Clearance Executive', 'manage_options', 'my_admin_menu', 'my_widget_settings', '', 3 );}
function my_add_widget_menu_exteranl_link() {
global $submenu;
$submenu['my_admin_menu'][500] = array( 'Admin Panel', 'manage_options' , 'http://google.co.uk' );
}
```

Comment: You cannot achieve a feature of HTML or Javascript with PHP. It's a backend scripting language.

You just need to output the target="_blank" attribute on the HTML anchor tag.

Comment: @i-CONICA i think the OP want's to know how to do this in wordpress, hence the tag *wordpress*

Comment: What you want actually?..

Comment: @AndreschSerj I got that. Wordpress is written in PHP, and it shown a flaw in the OPs understand of the separation between PHP and HTML by asking the question the way he did. So I was just stating that making a link open in a new tab is beyond the scope of the PHP scripting language.

Comment: @i-CONICA True. Excuse my nosy comment.

Comment: I understand that PHP cannot do this. What I wanted to know was how to /where to add a target blank. I thought I would need to break it out of the php and create a link but wasn't sure how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve a feature of HTML or Javascript with PHP. It's a backend scripting language. You just need to output the target="_blank" attribute on the HTML anchor tag.

Try:

```
array( 'Admin Panel', 'manage_options' , 'http://google.co.uk', array("target" => "_blank"))
```

From memory, I think that's how you pass in an array of attributes.

The WP documentation will confirm if that doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This didnt seem to work however I have been checking wordpress and it should accept 'target' => '_blank' I have tried it in a few different ways, but still no luck.

Answer (score -1):

Hello There I got a solution somewhere for the same requirements and it is working fine... Just use below provided script anywhere in HTML code section.
complete the script tags as it was not getting published properly..
Add Script Tags According before and after:-

$(document).ready(function() {
      $('a[href^="http://"]').filter(function() {return this.hostname && this.hostname !== location.hostname;}).attr('target', '_blank');
   });

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```